# Adding status message to mail

Tags: hooks, forms

currently I'm using two hooks in my hook.module. hook_form_alter() and hook_mail_alter().

In hook_form_alter() I use drupal_get_messages() to retrieve the status message.

And I want to use hook_mail_alter() to add this message to the email. But I can't pass the message content from one hook to the other.

A global variable is not working. Is there a better way? Another hook I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have tried to use `drupal_get_messages()` within `hook_mail_alter()` as well?

The reason it probably did not return a value is because the default behavior or `drupal_get_messages()` is to clear the message queue (so it empty the second time). You can however make it persistent by passing FALSE as a second parameter (see the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7.x)).

So in your `hook_form_alter()` use `drupal_get_messages(NULL, FALSE)` and then you should be able to use it again in `hook_mail_alter()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get the messages from within hook_mail_alter() because it is a form in a form. The outer form has the status message and the inner form is sending the mail. (And I'm not aloud to edit comments)

Comment: Have you tried it? The status messages are retrieved with [`drupal_set_message()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x) and that pulls them from `$_SESSION['messages']`. As long as you do not reset the queue it should be available in every function. (Assuming you do not use iframe to other sites, then there is nothing you can do) .

Comment: Hm, the whole reason I started fiddeling with two hooks was because drupal_get_messages() returned only an empty array. I'm not retrieving them anywhere but in hook_mail_alter().

Comment: They are displayed by the form before I'm trying to get them with drupal_get_messages(). Does this pull them out of the $_SESSION['messages'] too? If so, how could I prohibit this behaviour?

Comment: The messages are only available during the request in which they are generated. If you load multiple pages (eg subsequent form submissions) they are gone. You should send the mail in the same request in which the messages are generated.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible, hence the experiment with two hooks and a global variable. Maybe I can pass the message by javascript into the second request.

Comment: You could also attempt to store it in another session variable  that is not emptied at the end of a request. (regular session variables persist between page requests, but Drupal explicitly clears this one to prevent messages from stacking up) Then keep it there until you need it and empty the variable. (If you need help with that, please post it as a new question, referencing this one if required.)